# How to call another zpl file from the main zpl program

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a zpl script to print a logo, which is rather lengthy. Since this script file will be called once per label while printing other barcode labels, I would like to know if there is a way to embed (or import) the logo printing script in the main zpl script. The logo itself is a .png image, which I have converted to a zpl script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Send logo to the printer.  The `^ISR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS` is what saves the object to memory. Replace the rest with your logo.

   ```
   ^XA
   ^FO30,40^ADN,36,20^FDThis is my Logo^FS
   ^ISR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS
   ^XZ
   ```
2. Send the label to the printer, recalling the logo.  `^ILR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS` is what recalls the object from memory

   ```
   ^XA
   ^ILR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS
   ^FO150,125^ADN,36,20^FDFormatting Not In Logo^FS
   ^XZ
   ```

Make sure you

- Begin and end all streams with the begin and end commands: `^XA` (content) `^XZ`
- Use the memory path/letter that corresponds to the non-volatile memory.